# Fatal Error - Class 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider' not found (phpMailer)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, gmail, composer-php, phpmailer

I installed `league/oauth2-client` with composer and it created this line in `composer.json`

> "league/oauth2-client": "2.2.0"
>   [image]

When I refreshed `get_oauth_token.php` page, this error still came out:

> Fatal error: Class 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider'
>   not found in C:\xampp\htdocs...\PHPMailer\get_oauth_token.php on
>   line 35

Here's `get_oauth_token.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Get an OAuth2 token from Google.
 * * Install this script on your server so that it's accessible
 * as [https/http]://<yourdomain>/<folder>/get_oauth_token.php
 * e.g.: http://localhost/phpmail/get_oauth_token.php
 * * Ensure dependencies are installed with 'composer install'
 * * Set up an app in your Google developer console
 * * Set the script address as the app's redirect URL
 * If no refresh token is obtained when running this file, revoke access to your app
 * using link: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens and run the script again.
 * This script requires PHP 5.4 or later
 * PHP Version 5.4
 */

namespace League\OAuth2\Client\Provider;

require './vendor/autoload.php';

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Tool\BearerAuthorizationTrait;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

session_start();

//If this automatic URL doesn't work, set it yourself manually
$redirectUri = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
//$redirectUri = 'http://localhost/phpmailer/get_oauth_token.php';

//These details obtained are by setting up app in Google developer console.
$clientId = 'RANDOMCHARS-----duv1n2.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$clientSecret = 'RANDOMCHARS-----lGyjPcRtvP';

class Google extends AbstractProvider
{
    use BearerAuthorizationTrait;

    const ACCESS_TOKEN_RESOURCE_OWNER_ID = 'id';

    /**
     * @var string If set, this will be sent to google as the "access_type" parameter.
     * @link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline
     */
    protected $accessType;

    /**
     * @var string If set, this will be sent to google as the "hd" parameter.
     * @link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#hd-param
     */
    protected $hostedDomain;

    /**
     * @var string If set, this will be sent to google as the "scope" parameter.
     * @link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes
     */
    protected $scope;

    public function getBaseAuthorizationUrl()
    {
        return 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
    }

    public function getBaseAccessTokenUrl(array $params)
    {
        return 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    }

    public function getResourceOwnerDetailsUrl(AccessToken $token)
    {
    return ' ';
    }

    protected function getAuthorizationParameters(array $options)
    {
    if (is_array($this->scope)) {
            $separator = $this->getScopeSeparator();
            $this->scope = implode($separator, $this->scope);
        }

        $params = array_merge(
            parent::getAuthorizationParameters($options),
            array_filter([
                'hd'          => $this->hostedDomain,
                'access_type' => $this->accessType,
        'scope'       => $this->scope,
                // if the user is logged in with more than one account ask which one to use for the login!
                'authuser'    => '-1'
            ])
        );
        return $params;
    }

    protected function getDefaultScopes()
    {
        return [
            'email',
            'openid',
            'profile',
        ];
    }

    protected function getScopeSeparator()
    {
        return ' ';
    }

    protected function checkResponse(ResponseInterface $response, $data)
    {
        if (!empty($data['error'])) {
            $code  = 0;
            $error = $data['error'];

            if (is_array($error)) {
                $code  = $error['code'];
                $error = $error['message'];
            }

            throw new IdentityProviderException($error, $code, $data);
        }
    }

    protected function createResourceOwner(array $response, AccessToken $token)
    {
        return new GoogleUser($response);
    }
}


//Set Redirect URI in Developer Console as [https/http]://<yourdomain>/<folder>/get_oauth_token.php
$provider = new Google(
    array(
        'myClientId' => $clientId, //already inserted
        'myClientSecret' => $clientSecret, //already inserted
        'myRedirectUri' => $redirectUri, //already inserted
        'scope' => array('https://mail.google.com/'),
    'accessType' => 'offline'
    )
);

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit;
// Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state');
} else {
    // Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken(
        'authorization_code',
        array(
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        )
    );

    // Use this to get a new access token if the old one expires
    echo 'Refresh Token: ' . $token->getRefreshToken();
}
```

Can you explain me in detail what to do after having installed `league/oauth2-client` through `composer require league/oauth2-client`?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: @aynber What is that?

Comment: It's a command that you run on the command line. It helps your program find any new classes and packages, and should be run anytime you install a new package.

Comment: I recommend trying the as-yet-unreleased [PHPMailer version 6.0](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/6.0). The XOAUTH2 support is much improved (along with many other things). Any outstanding issues do not relate to that, and any feedback on it would be much appreciated!

Comment: @aynber It's strange because I used `composer require league/oauth2-client` opening the command window in a specific location (in this case phpMailer folder). What if I try to search this  `League\OAuth2\Client\Provider` in my pc. Should I find the files right?

Comment: @Synchro Do I have to type `"phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0"` in `composer.json` to update it?

Comment: You should be editing the composer.json for your own project, not PHPMailer's own composer.json, otherwise you risk breaking the ability to upgrade through composer in future. The golden rule for composer is that you should never have to touch files inside the vendor folder.

Comment: Look on the releases page and specify one of the `rc` releases explicitly. By default composer will not pull pre-release versions.

Comment: If it doesn't find it, you can try `composer install` or `composer update`. Then run `composer dumpautoload` to update your autoloader.

Answer (score 9):

Had a similar issue and discovered its not stated explicitly in the official tutorial [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2). 
The library league/oauth2-client requires you to install the provider you need seperately as there are multiple providers both official and third party [here](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/tree/master/docs/providers).

For google provider you would need

```
composer require league/oauth2-google
```

And refer to it like this

```
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;
```